# Размещение item с текстом под item с картинкой в toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-menu

Интересует возможность размещения menu item с текстом под item с картинкой внутри toolbar android. Пока получается только рядом.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:title="@string/News" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="@string/Settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/change_cur"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/usd"
        android:title="Change cur"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:title="@string/about" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cur_name"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:title="cur_name"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

[image: Примерный макет]

Comment: Toolbar для этого не предназначен. Если вас не устраивает стандартная реализация, то придётся своими руками всё делать в виде отдельного куска разметки со всей нужной логикой.

Comment: спасибо за коммент